# Hardware 3D acceleration suddenly stopped working

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia

I turned on my laptop the other day and noticed that Gnome was not using fancy graphics mode. As far as I know there is no reason my drivers should have stopped working, as I haven't made any upgrades or changes to the system. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I've upgraded it some time ago so it has nothing to do with the upgrade. 
The only odd behaviour I can think of is that I played Eufloria and after I exited it, it failed to restore my previous resolution.

I have already tried following the advice found [here](https://www.benjaminwiedmann.net/fix-nouveau-driver-issues-on-ubuntu-12-04-install-nvidia-drivers.html) and [here](http://dragly.org/2012/05/04/installing-the-nvidia-driver-in-kubuntu-12-04/) but with no results. Moreover, at some step during these processes I get the following warnings:

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/sda1
cryptsetup: WARNING: could not determine root device from /etc/fstab
cryptsetup: WARNING: failed to detect canonical device of /dev/sda5
```